# Typo3: How to insert the page title automatically into an img alt tag and into rtetextarea

Tags: typo3, rte, typoscript

Say we have a Text/Images record and go to "Images & Captions" and then to "Alternative Labels (one per line)".

> I would like something like this: "this is the alt image info for
>   {page:title}."

Using {page:title} in the "main" page elements like "General>Header" works, but not for "Images>Alternative Labels (one per line)"

Also, would the solution to the above work similarly "{page:title}" in the RTEtextarea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this will do:

```
temp.altText >
temp.altText < tt_content.image.20.1.altText
tt_content.image.20.1.altText >
tt_content.image.20.1.altText.cObject = COA
tt_content.image.20.1.altText.cObject {
    10 < temp.altText
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        noTrimWrap = | | |
        data = page:title
    }
}
```

It uses the original alt attributes and appends the page title of the current page. 
I don't know about a way to accomplish that in inline RTE images though. The alt text is set within the sourcecode, image tags are not specifically parsed by `lib.parseFunc_RTE` during the rendering process

Comment: Hello konsolenfreddy,
The typoscript (included in an Extension template) overwrites the whole Alt tag to give: <img ... alt="COA" ...>
Please have another look at your code. I'd like to debug but I'm not quite there yet ...

Comment: Sorry HowarK, I've missed a `cObject`. It's working now, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nearly there ... the page:title is indeed inserted into the alt tag but the original alt tag attributes are not appended; they are 'overwritten' by the page title. I've tried fiddling with the code but no luck yet ... eventually I will have a decent knowledge of Tscript vs luck ...

Comment: Hello @konsolenfreddy , I'm not sure if my last question was automatically sent to you. If yes, sorry to bother. If no, further debugging help will be much appreciated. (original attributes are not being appended)

Comment: Hello @konslefredd,
Fixed bug by removing one Pipe from 'noTrimWrap = | | |' to give:  'noTrimWrap = | |' . With 3 Pipes, the original Alt attributes is not included.

Comment: Ai, only 5 minutes allowed for editing. Again:
Hello @konslefreddy,
Fixed bug by removing one Pipe from 'noTrimWrap = | | |' to give:  'noTrimWrap = | |' . With 3 Pipes, the original Alt attributes is not included when the pageTitle is appended.

Comment: That's odd. TSREF suggests that 3 pipes are needed http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/stdWrap#noTrimWrap But I'm glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This lines of coude should do the same thing.

```
tt_content.image.20.1.altText.append = TEXT
tt_content.image.20.1.altText.append {
   noTrimWrap = | ||
   data = page:title
}
```

If the editor should be able to set {page:title} of its own, just set

```
tt_content.image.20.1.altText.insertData = 1
```